# PhpStorm - can't enable zen coding

Tags: phpstorm, java, emmet

Since i've just installed PhpStorm yesterday, I'm trying to get zen coding feature to work.

I have looked through here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/zen-coding-support.html

So it looks like there is some kind of default zen coding installed, but I couldn't get it to work.

[Here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2010/03/zen-coding-support-in-webstormphpstorm/) they are saying that hitting form.form-comment#comment>fieldset following by a TAB should work - but it didn't.

Could it be anything to do with that I'm running OpenJDK?

Thanks!

Edit: I should add that this is the PhpStorm trial version - Can it be that?

Comment: Did you activate it under `Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) -> IDE Settings -> Editor -> Smart Keys -> Enable Zen Coding`?

Comment: 1) It does work here (Windows 7); 2) Trial version has no functionality limitations, only time restriction; 3) OpenJDK? -- don't know.

Comment: I got it working - after all that research I got to this disappointing conclusion :) I was under the php scope :)

Comment: for everybody finding this post, it's called Emmet now (http://docs.emmet.io/) and is directly integrated since 5.0 I think

Comment: @AndPy +1 How did you managed to switch from php scope to enable emmet in .html?